# US Letter or A4 PDF - which is better for iPad?

Tags: ipad, pdf

I am given the option to download a US Letter or A4 formatted PDF - Which fits the iPad screen better?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Letter.  A4 is slightly longer and narrower than US Letter, and would result in wider borders at the side to fit a full page vertically.  US Letter won't fit perfectly, but the aspect ratio of it's dimensions are a much closer fit to the iPads 4:3 (or 3:4 in portrait) screen and the slimmer borders top and bottom would be less noticeable than the A4 equivalent:

```
        Millimetres Inches   

        Width   Length  Width   Length
A4      210.0   297.0   8.26    11.69 (3:4.24 APPROX)
```

or 6% too long when scaled to fit the shortest edge, resulting in vertical borders when scaled to fit the longest edge

```
Letter  215.9   279.4   8.50    11.00 (3:3.88 APPROX)
```

or 3% too short when scaled to fit the shortest edge, resulting in horizontal borders when scaled to fit the longest edge

See [this link](http://betweenborders.com/wordsmithing/a4-vs-us-letter/) for good comparative info and [this one](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/) for a ratio calculator